# Definition of joint density for continuous random variables: order of partial derivatives

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

This is a description of continuous random variables from Wikipedia. For a pair of random variables $X,Y$, the joint cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_{XY}$ is given by $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\le x, Y \le y).$$

Now the joint probability density function is given by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}.$$

My question is: Does the order of the partial differentiation not matter here? It wouldn't matter if $F$ has continuous second partial derivatives. But I don't think this condition is given. But then I can't see why we should take the derivative w.r.t $y$ first then $x$. Perhaps this is because we have the joint distribution for the order $(X,Y)$ and if we have $(Y,X)$ then it should be $\partial y \partial x$ in the denominator? I would greatly appreciate some explanation.

Comment: Partial derivatives in distribution sense always commute.

Comment: @Yuval Why do they commute?

Comment: Actually I am not sure if that is what you need in this context. For derivatives in distribution sense, you may check https://www.math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math456/GREENS1.pdf

Comment: Say page 27 on the above slides. Basically, the order of partial derivatives can be exchanged on the test functions, so can be exchanged on the distribution itself.

Comment: @Yuval Well I don't think this is the kind of distribution I am dealing with.